# scroll bar is not showing

Tags: css, layout, scroll

i am making a website, where the scroll bar is not showing in any browser.....in firefox i can use down key to move downwards in chrome it worst...i am showing my codes below and i used div tag for division of page..
any suggestion:

- globalheader-->at top of page;
- globalnav-->should be at left hand side with fixed position no effect of scrolling.
- globalcontent-->at the middle of page, here i show all data and results.
- globalright-->at the right hand side of page-

css code:

```
html { overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; overflow-y: scroll; height: 101%;}
body{ padding:0px; margin:0px; }

#globalheader{width:930px; height:28px;background:#fff; z-index:1; position:absolute;
                margin: 15px 200px 0px 200px; padding: 1px; float:left;  border:0px solid;  }  


#globalnav { float:left; margin:120px 0px 0px 0px; padding:0px; background:#FFF; z-index:2;
            position:fixed; left:0px; overflow:visible;   width:150px; height:auto;           border:0px solid #ababab;}

#globalright{  margin-top:50px; height:auto; width:205px; position: absolute; left:1055px;   
              right:0px; top:50px; border:#cdcdcd 0px solid;    }


#globalcontent{ margin:50px 105px 20px 215px; border:#aaa 1px solid;  height:900px;

                    float:left; width:761px;  border-top:none;}
```

Comment: Why does your content have a fixed height?

Comment: @joshuanhibbert actually ....what im trying to do is, to make easy for user to navigate in any page

Answer (score 1):

For `#globalcontent`'s style use, `min-height:900px;`, instead of `height:900px;`
Also, `100%`, not `101%` for `html`'s height.

More importantly, consider using a standard, tried-and-proven layout, like ["The Perfect 3 Column Liquid Layout"](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm) ([et cetera](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=3+column+layout)) instead of reinventing the wheel unnecessarily.